# Binary search implementations

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I'm stuck in implementing 5 different ways of binary chop ( task http://codekata.com/kata/kata02-karate-chop/ ). May you give some ideas for more approaches?
That's what I have got:

1)

```
def left_chop(key, arr):
    l = 0
    r = len(arr)
    while l<r:
        m = (l+r)/2
        if key<=arr[m]:
            r = m 
        else:
            l = m+1
    return l if key == arr[l] else -1
```

2)

```
def left_chop(key, array, left = 0, right = None):
    if right == None:
        right = len(array)
    if left==right:
        return left if key == array[left] else -1
    m = (left+right)/2
    if key<=array[m]:
        return left_chop(key, array, left, m)
    else:
        return left_chop(key, array, m+1, right)
```

3)I know, it's very similar to first

```
class find(object):
    def __init__(self, key, array):
        self.array = array
        self.key = key
        self.l = 0
        self.r = len(array)

    def left_chop(self):
        while self.l<self.r:
            self.step()
        return self.l if self.key == self.array[self.l] else -1

    def step(self):
        m = (self.l+self.r)/2
        if self.key<=self.array[m]:
            self.r = m
        else:
            self.l = m+1
```

I had tried to come up with something in functional programming style, but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Python is not a language best suited to functional programming, if you like functional you would love scala, there also also bisection algorithms in the bisect module in pure python

Comment: Thanks I will try scala. There are such module, but it uses approach similar to first: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py

Comment: The first one isn't valid Python.

Comment: The pragmatic python approach would be to use existing methods like ``bisect.bisect_left()`` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) or ``numpy.searchsorted()`` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Arguably that is probably not the approach you had in mind. But you could take a look at the source code.

Comment: You might find the site Rosetta Code useful. It shows you implementations of an algorithm in multiple languages and styles. Here's the [Binary Search](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search) page and the [Python](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Python) section.

Comment: What do you mean by functional style? A functional language would likely use recursion to solve this problem, exactly as you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator:

```
def chopper(array, val):
    edges = (0, len(array))
    while True:
        m = sum(edges)/2
        edges = (edges[0], m) if array[m] >= val else (m+1, edges[1])
        yield edges

def chopSearch(array, val):
    for l, r in chopper(array, val):
        if array[l] == val:
            return l
        if l==r:
            return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

4) This one uses recursion. If the halfway is correct, it returns the index. Otherwise, it splits the array in half and continues searching in that manner.

```
def getIndexOf(search, array):
    arrlen = len(array)
    halfindex = arrlen / 2 - ((arrlen % 2) / 2)
    value = array[halfindex]
    if len(array) < 2 and array[0] != search:
        return -1;
    if value == search:
        return halfindex
    elif search < value:
        return getIndexOf(search, array[0:halfindex])
    else:
        return getIndexOf(search, array[halfindex:arrlen] + halfindex)
```

Comment: I edited it so that it won't exceed maximum recursion depth if the search didn't exist in the array

Comment: that addition of `if search not in array` defeats the whole idea behind binary search, doesn't it? In the first recursion it will do a full run through the `array`... you probably want `if len(array) < 2 and search != array[0]: return -1`. Also there's a `)` too much in your last line...

Answer (score 1):

1.A straightforward implementation of the binary search algorithm.

```
def binary_search(seq, t):
min = 0
max = len(seq) - 1
  while True:
     if max < min:
       return -1
       m = (min + max) // 2
     if seq[m] < t:
       min = m + 1
     elseif seq[m] > t:
       max = m - 1
   else:
      return m
```

2. Alternative approach for binary search.

   ```
   def binarySearch(alist, item):
       first = 0
       last = len(alist)-1
       found = False
   while first<=last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last)//2
   if alist[midpoint] == item:
      found = True
    else
   if item < alist[midpoint]:
   last = midpoint-1
    else:
   first = midpoint+1
       return found
   testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
   print(binarySearch(testlist, 3))
   print(binarySearch(testlist, 13))
   ```

3.Third different way for handling binary search in python programming

```
   def binarySearch(alist, item):
        if len(alist) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            midpoint = len(alist)//2
            if alist[midpoint]==item:
              return True
            else:
              if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item)
              else:
                return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item)
        testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
       print(binarySearch(testlist, 3))
       print(binarySearch(testlist, 13))
```

Comment: Link broken; btw., +1 for using slices :)

Comment: How exactly is that better then OP's first snippet? I feel like it's much cleaner than any of your three options

Answer (score -1):

Randomized split search.

1. Current node = root.
2. Repeat while not found.

   - If current node = required value, found.
   - If the required integer is less than the root, randomly pick an index from 0 to index(root). Set current node = picked index.
   - Else, randomly pick an index from root to n-1. Set current node = picked index.

Comment: In the worst case it works in O (n), which is not quite a binary search, but thanks! It's interesting approach.

Comment: We are still chopping, so it is still binary. The only change is that instead of going to the next child in a binary search, we pick a random child from all generations of the current node. So worst case would still be log(n). With large datasets, randomization has proved to be an effective technique for optimization, hence the approach.

Answer (score -1):

Functional programming implies multiple functions, each with their own single purpose, which return the same output for a given input:

```
def chopSearch(array, value):
    while len(array) != 1:
        if value == getMiddle(array):
            return value
        else:
            array = getNewArray(array, lessThan(array, value))
    return if array[0] == value value else -1

def getMiddle(array):
    return if (len(array) % 2 == 0) array[len(array)/2] else array[(len(array)+1)/2]

def lessThan(array, value):
    return if getMiddle(array) > value true else false

def getNewArray(array, isLess):
    return if isLess array[0:getMiddle(array)] else array[getMiddle(array)+1:len(array)-1]
```

As a caviat, I don't know python so it took me a minute to try and write this. Feel free to fix any pyton mistakes you see.

Answer (score -1):

Courtesy of PSF

```
In [1]: import bisect

In [2]: bisect??
def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```